# Android : opening existing Android project

Tags: android, eclipse, ide

When I import an existing project or create a new project it create it but show this windows which does not shows package pane to show files list.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`goto window menu >> Show View >> Package Explorer`  now you can show package explorer at left side.you can show you import project

Answer (score 2):

Go to

Window > Show View > Package Explorer.